# Is conjugation in infinite groups well behaved?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

A question from earlier today made me start to think of this question. Let $G$ be an infinite group with infinite subgroup $H$. Can the condition below ever hold?

\begin{equation*}
\exists g\in G \text{ such that } gHg^{-1}\subset H
\end{equation*}

where the containment above is strict.

Comment: I take it $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ means that $gHg^{-1}$ is a *proper* subset of $H$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!

Comment: Yes, and this has been asked many times before. On the right of my screen, I am seeing a list of related questions, and the very first of these is the identical question to yours.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for pointing that out to me; I'm still learning this site!