# Conjugacy of maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

This is inspired by my earlier duplicate question seen here: [Is conjugation in infinite groups well behaved?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091138/is-conjugation-in-infinite-groups-well-behaved)

The answer to that question is no. This slight tweak might change the result, but I don't have much intuition for infinite groups (who does?).

Let $G$ be an infinite group, and let $M$ be a maximal subgroup (in the sense that there are no proper subgroups of $G$ containing $M$ that aren't $M$). Is it possible for $gMg^{-1}\subset M$, with the containment being proper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be $gMg^{-1}$, suppose that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Notice that $M=g^{-1}Hg$ is properly contained in $g^{-1}Mg$, so $g^{-1}Mg$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ that contains $M$ properly, contradicting the maximality of $M$.

---

Alteranatively: Note that conjugation is an automorphism, so by the correspondence isomorphism theorem it sends maximal subgroups to maximal subgroups.